# show small line near h-axis labels

Tags: google-visualization

I am working on google chart API. I have a column chart where i want to show a small line near every label shown near h-axis as shown in the sample image below.
[image]

What modifications need to be done to show the small line near each label shown on h-axis.

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/8tvm9qk5/

js code:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStacked);

function drawStacked() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Departamentos');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Entregados');
      data.addColumn('number', 'En Stock');

      data.addRows([
        ['abdasdasa', 925, 786],
        ['bbdasdas', 652, 156],
        ['cbdasdas', 300, 200],
        ['ddasdasb', 925, 786],
        ['edasdb', 652, 156],
        ['fasdasb', 300, 200],
        ['gdasdasdb', 925, 786],
        ['abdasdasa', 925, 786],
        ['bbdasdas', 652, 156],
        ['cbdasdas', 300, 200],
        ['ddasdasb', 925, 786],
        ['edasdb', 652, 156],
        ['fasdasb', 300, 200],
        ['gdasdasdb', 925, 786]
      ]);
     var options = {
        title: 'Motivation and Energy Level Throughout the Day',
        isStacked: true,
        height:600,
        chartArea: {
            height:300,
          top:100,
        },
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Departamentos',
          titleTextStyle: {
            color: '#FF0000',            
          },

          slantedText:true,
          slantedTextAngle:45,

        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Kits'
        }
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

--EDITED--
I tried as shown below, but could not get the expected result.

sample code:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'Departamentos');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Entregados');
      data.addColumn('number', 'En Stock');
      data.addColumn('number', 'dumy');
      data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'}); 
 data.addRows([
        ['abdasdasa', 925, 786,0, ''],
        ['bbdasdas', 652, 156,0, ''],
        ['cbdasdas', 300, 200,0, ''],
  .....]);
```

PS: I tried by interchanging the column sequence too:

```
 ...
 data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'}); 
 data.addColumn('number', 'dumy');
```

Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/1xq2nj16/

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48725928/5090771)...

Comment: @WhiteHat - tick marks are shown at the top of the bars, how to show them near hAxis(bottom) of the chart as shown in the image above, any inputs would be helpful. Please find my updated demo which shows the tick mark at the top of the bars https://jsfiddle.net/2w2yLLsq/1/

Comment: the annotation column needs to follow a series column with all values of zero...

Comment: @WhiteHat - I tried as you suggested but could not get the expected result. Please see my edited section in the above post. Can you please provide sample code if possible? Demo https://jsfiddle.net/1xq2nj16/1/

Answer (score 0):

the dummy series needs to be first when --> `isStacked: true`
or change the series to a different type to break from the stack...
(see `series` option in following snippet)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Departamentos');
  data.addColumn('number', 'dumy');
  data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});  // interval role col.
  data.addColumn('number', 'Entregados');
  data.addColumn('number', 'En Stock');

  data.addRows([
    ['abdasdasa', 0, '', 925, 786],
    ['bbdasdas', 0, '', 652, 156],
    ['cbdasdas', 0, '', 300, 200],
    ['ddasdasb', 0, '', 925, 786],
    ['edasdb', 0, '', 652, 156],
    ['fasdasb', 0, '', 300, 200],
    ['gdasdasdb', 0, '', 925, 786],
    ['abdasdasa', 0, '', 925, 786],
    ['bbdasdas', 0, '', 652, 156],
    ['cbdasdas', 0, '', 300, 200],
    ['ddasdasb', 0, '', 925, 786],
    ['edasdb', 0, '', 652, 156],
    ['fasdasb', 0, '', 300, 200],
    ['gdasdasdb', 0, '', 925, 786]
  ]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      stem: {
        color: '#000000'
      },
      style: 'line',
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
    },
    title: 'Motivation and Energy Level Throughout the Day',
    isStacked: true,
    height: 600,
    chartArea: {
      height: 300,
      top: 100
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Departamentos',
      pointSize: 0,
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#ff0000',
      },
      slantedText: true,
      slantedTextAngle: 45
    },
    series: {
      0: {
        color: 'transparent',
        type: 'line',
        visibleInLegend: false,
        enableInteractivity: false
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Kits'
    }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

further adjustments can be made to get the tick mark below the x-axis,
use a negative dummy value, and tweak the y-axis to allow room for negative values...
(see `vAxis` options in the following snippet)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Departamentos');
  data.addColumn('number', 'dumy');
  data.addColumn({type:'string', role:'annotation'});  // interval role col.
  data.addColumn('number', 'Entregados');
  data.addColumn('number', 'En Stock');

  data.addRows([
    ['abdasdasa', -32, '', 925, 786],
    ['bbdasdas', -32, '', 652, 156],
    ['cbdasdas', -32, '', 300, 200],
    ['ddasdasb', -32, '', 925, 786],
    ['edasdb', -32, '', 652, 156],
    ['fasdasb', -32, '', 300, 200],
    ['gdasdasdb', -32, '', 925, 786],
    ['abdasdasa', -32, '', 925, 786],
    ['bbdasdas', -32, '', 652, 156],
    ['cbdasdas', -32, '', 300, 200],
    ['ddasdasb', -32, '', 925, 786],
    ['edasdb', -32, '', 652, 156],
    ['fasdasb', -32, '', 300, 200],
    ['gdasdasdb', -32, '', 925, 786]
  ]);

  var options = {
    annotations: {
      stem: {
        color: '#000000'
      },
      style: 'line',
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 10
      },
    },
    title: 'Motivation and Energy Level Throughout the Day',
    isStacked: true,
    height: 600,
    chartArea: {
      height: 300,
      top: 100
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Departamentos',
      pointSize: 0,
      titleTextStyle: {
        color: '#ff0000',
      },
      slantedText: true,
      slantedTextAngle: 45
    },
    series: {
      0: {
        color: 'transparent',
        type: 'line',
        visibleInLegend: false,
        enableInteractivity: false
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      ticks: [0, 500, 1000, 1500, 2000],
      title: 'Kits',
      viewWindow: {
        min: -64
      }
    }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```