# Is it possible to draw tick marks outside of the X-Axis on Google Charts?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I've done quite a bit of research of google charts(specifically combo chart) and I don't think producing this UI is possible:
[image]

This is because:

1. Gridlines in Google Chart only go inward the graph.
2. "Ticks" are available, but only as labels.

I don't see any other option to create this effects. Any ideas on how to create this effect?

Comment: check the second example, here --> [show small line near h-axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49173558/5090771)

Comment: @WhiteHat. Is it possible to create varied tick lengths like shown above? It seems like annotations.textSize controls the length of the tick, and that cannot vary, only a constant. Thanks