# How to add ticks to a Google line chart in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, graph, google-visualization, linechart

I'm trying to add tick marks to my Google line chart, but when I input `ticks: [0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]` on my vertical axis and `ticks: [400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650]` on my horizontal axis, they keep appearing more as gridlines than actual tick marks.

[image: I've created this chart through Google Sheets. I've checkboxed both major and minor ticks, and this is how I want my Google line chart to look like through my code.]

[image: This is how my chart looks through Javascript, some CSS, and some HTML. As you can see, the tick marks look more like gridlines than the major and minor tick marks in Google Sheets.]

For the Google Sheets line chart I created, MAJOR and MINOR ticks are checkboxed. [Major Count: Auto, Minor Count: 1]

For the MAJOR ticks:

- Positions on the HORIZONTAL AXIS would be at [400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650]
- Positions on the VERTICAL AXIS would be at [0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0]
- Ticks Position: Cross (so it would cross the baseline, rather than being inside or outside of it)
- Ticks Length: 12px
- Line Thickness: 1px
- Line Color: Black

For the MINOR ticks:

- Positions on the HORIZONTAL AXIS would be at [425, 475, 525, 575, 625]
- Positions on the VERTICAL AXIS would be at [0.25, 0.75, 1.25, 1.75]
- Ticks Position: Cross
- Ticks Length: 6px
- Line Thickness: 1px
- Line Color: Black

Here is my code:

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawLineColors);

function drawLineColors() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Absorbance');

      data.addRows([
        [380, 0.12],    
        [390, 0.098],   
        [400, 0.088],  
        [410, 0.12],   
        [420, 0.292],  
        [430, 0.302],
        [440, 0.444],   
        [450, 0.636],  
        [460, 0.774],  
        [470, 0.998],  
        [480, 1.428], 
        [490, 1.862],
        [500, 1.954], 
        [510, 1.45], 
        [520, 0.774], 
        [530, 0.364], 
        [540, 0.16], 
        [550, 0.134],
        [560, 0.074], 
        [570, 0.06], 
        [580, 0.076], 
        [590, 0.046], 
        [600, 0.0004], 
        [610, 0.008],
        [620, 0.006], 
        [630, 0.0006], 
        [640, 0.016], 
        [650, 0.002], 
        [660, 0.056], 
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Analytical Spectrum',
        
        titleTextStyle: {
          fontName: 'Courier Prime', 
          fontSize: 30, 
          bold: true, 
          color: 'black' },
          
        height: 500,
        width: 900,
         
      
        hAxis: 
        {
          title: 'Wavelength (nm)',
          titleTextStyle: {
            fontName: 'Courier Prime',
            fontSize: 18,
            bold: true,
            italic: false },
          textStyle: {
            fontName: 'Courier Prime',
            fontSize: 16,
            bold: true,
            color: 'black'
          },

          gridlines: {count: '0'},
          minTextSpacing: '1',
          baseline: '380',
          ticks: [400, 450, 500, 550, 600, 650]
        },
          
        vAxis: 
        {
        title: 'Absorbance (AU)',
        titleTextStyle: {
          fontName: 'Courier Prime',
          fontSize: 18,
          bold: true,
          italic: false },
        textStyle: {
          fontName: 'Courier Prime',
          fontSize: 16,
          bold: true,
          color: 'black'
        },

        gridlines: {count: '0'},
        baseline: '0',
        ticks: [0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0],
        },
        
        
        legend: 'none',
        
        lineWidth: 5,
          
        colors: ['#0000ff']
   
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('AnalyticalSpectrum'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

I've been using this Google Line Chart overview under "Configuration Options" to check how I can change my tick marks, but I'm not yet seeing anything that explains why the tick marks are showing up as gridlines, or how to change that: [https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart].

Comment: Do the `ticks` show up when you hover over a rendered line charts line? Also are only looking to have marks with no connecting lines?

Comment: check second example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49173558/5090771)