# Tickmarks in Google Script for Charts

Tags: google-apps-script, charts

I'm not sure if this is the right terminology or not but I'm looking for tickmarks (see image below):

[image]

Based on what I found online at this link:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

It makes it seem as though this is just overriding the values at the hAxis and doesn't actually add any new lines.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a link to the document: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17bvRZ58MWnFYAvNfIOU6d1LuzLepVb9ZmjbRUFvqw3w/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks!

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Comment: It's in the script of the doc, but it's this:                  chart.setOption('hAxis',{ticks:[new Date(2018,10,2),new Date(2018,1,5)]}); although like I had mentioned before I'm not sure if this is actually what tickmarks are.

Comment: It's better form to paste the script into the question so people don't have to jump back and forth. Also, your script is view only, and few will be willing to make a copy into their own Google Drive to debug.

Comment: there's not a config option for this, but you can get there using an annotation, check this answer --> [Google Charts no gridlines but I want the ticks to have a black marker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48725928/5090771)